# Angular 2 call service only on app initialization

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-injection

What I am trying to accomplish is to call external API only once per app initialization.

I have a simple service,

```
@Injectable()
export class XService {
    url = "http://api.example.com"
    constructor(private _http:Http) {

    }

    callAnAPI(){
        console.log('made an external request");
        return this._http.get(url)
            .map(res=>res.json());
    }
}
```

and two components, the main `appComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      Test
    </div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
    isLoading = true;
    results = [];

    constructor(private _service: XService){

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        Observable.forkJoin(
            this._service.callAnAPI()
            // some more services here
        )
        .subscribe(
            res => {
                this.results = res[0];
            },
            null,
            () => {this.isLoading = false}
        );
    }
}
```

and another component used with a route

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
      I want to use the service with this component.
    </div>
  `
})

export class SecondComponent {

    constructor(private _service: XService){

    }
}
```

the service is initialized and Angular hits server on the initialization of the `AppComponent`.  I want to Use `XService` with `SecondComponent` too, whenever I try to call the service again from the `SecondComponent`, (via `_service._service.callAnAPI()`) Angular hits the external API. I want to minimize the external hits.

How do I obtain the data made by the `AppComponent` on initialization than calling again the service again in `SecondComponent`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `do` operator for this to get the data the first time and reuse them for next calls:

```
@Injectable()
export class XService {
  url = "http://api.example.com"
  constructor(private _http:Http) {

  }

  callAnAPI(){
    console.log('made an external request");
    if (this.cachedData) {
      return Observable.of(this.cachedData);
    } else {
      return this._http.get(url)
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .do((data) => {
          this.cachedData = data;
        });
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to load data as startup, you can call the `callAnAPI` method from the service constructor.

To be able to use this approach, you need to define your service when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ XService ]);
```

This way you will use a single instance for your whole application.

Comment: how to bootstrap this service in angular 2.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Injectable()
export class XService {
    url = "http://api.example.com"
    constructor(private _http:Http) {

    }

    callAnAPI(){
      if(this.data) {
        return Observable.of(this.data);
      } else {
        console.log('made an external request");
        return this._http.get(url)
            .map(res=>res.json())
            .do(res => this.data = res);
      }
    }
}
```